# Cambio de precios y formas de financiación en Argentina ¿como se va a adaptar Mercado Pago?

Tags: mercadopago

Mi pregunta se refiere al cambio que quiere implementar el gobierno de Argentina en relación a que se debe publicar un precio de contado y uno de financiación. 
La pregunta es, ¿como se va a manejar en Mercado pago este tema de los precios? Actualmente a mp en el checkout sólo se envía un precio y a partir de eso se calculan las cuotas y demás, pero a partir del cambio que quiere implemetnar el gobierno se deben mostrar 2 precios, uno para contado y otro para la financiación en cuotas.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no tiene nada que ver con la programación.

Comment: @Martin Acevedo mercado pago esta trabajando en estos días en realizar los cambios correspondientes para mostrar en sus checkouts la informacion correspondiente a la reglamentación y los textos sugeridos para las cuotas en los API's deacuerdo a la misma.